# R - Combining linetype and color in ggplot2 legend while legend labels represent expressions

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Given the following data:

```
data <- data.frame(Train = rep(c(20,30,40,50),2), xi = runif(8,0,1), category = c(rep("0.3_val",4),rep("0.3_test",4)))
data <- rbind(data, data.frame(Train = rep(c(20,30,40,50),2), xi = runif(8,0,1), category = c(rep("0.6_val",4),rep("0.6_test",4))))
```

If I am considering the data from the code above, the legends of linetype and color are merged into one legend:

```
p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Train, y = xi, group = category, color = category)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = category,linetype=category)) +  
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab(expression(italic("n"))) + 
  ylab(expression(xi)) + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),                                                                                                                                                      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), legend.title=element_text(size=4)) +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.2, 'cm')) + guides(fill=guide_legend(title=ylab)) + 
  theme(strip.background =element_rect(color = "black",fill="white")) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend", values=c("black","black","grey","grey"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(name="Legend", values=c("dashed", "twodash","dashed", "twodash","dashed", "twodash"))

print(p)
```

If now the legend labels get changed with greek symbols (expressions), the legends are split in two although the name and labels are identical in scale_x_manual():

```
p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Train, y = xi, group = category, color = category)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = category,linetype=category)) +  
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab(expression(italic("n"))) + 
  ylab(expression(xi)) + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),                                                                                                                                                      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), legend.title=element_text(size=4)) +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.2, 'cm')) + guides(fill=guide_legend(title=ylab)) + 
  theme(strip.background =element_rect(color = "black",fill="white")) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend", values=c("black","black","grey","grey"),
                      labels=c("0.3_val"=expression(xi[0.3]^{val}),
                               "0.3_test"=expression(xi[0.3]^{test}),
                               "0.6_val"=expression(xi[0.6]^{val}),
                               "0.6_test"=expression(xi[0.6]^{test})))+
  scale_linetype_manual(name="Legend", values=c("dashed", "twodash","dashed", "twodash"),
                        labels=c("0.3_val"=expression(xi[0.3]^{val}),
                                 "0.3_test"=expression(xi[0.3]^{test}),
                                 "0.6_val"=expression(xi[0.6]^{val}),
                                 "0.6_test"=expression(xi[0.6]^{test})))

print(p)
```

How can I avoid this problem to have just one instead of two legends when using expressions in scale_x_manual()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch off the linetype guide and override the aesthetics of the color guide:

```r
ggplot(data = data,
       aes(x = Train, y = xi, group = category)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = category, color = category)) +  
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab(expression(italic("n"))) + 
  ylab(expression(xi)) + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend", values=c("black","black","grey","grey"),
                      labels=c("0.3_val"  = expression(xi[0.3]^{val}),
                               "0.3_test" = expression(xi[0.3]^{test}),
                               "0.6_val"  = expression(xi[0.6]^{val}),
                               "0.6_test" = expression(xi[0.6]^{test}))) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c("dashed", 
                              "twodash","dashed", "twodash")))) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Legend", 
                        guide = 'none',
                        values = c("dashed", "twodash","dashed", "twodash"))
```

[image]

For some reason, storing your labels as an expression object beforehand also works, and requires a bit less typing:

```r
labs <- c("0.3_val"  = expression(xi[0.3]^{val}),
          "0.3_test" = expression(xi[0.3]^{test}),
          "0.6_val"  = expression(xi[0.6]^{val}),
          "0.6_test" = expression(xi[0.6]^{test}))

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Train, y = xi, group = category)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = category, color = category)) +  
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab(expression(italic("n"))) + 
  ylab(expression(xi)) + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Legend", labels = labs,
                      values = c("black","black","grey","grey")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Legend", labels = labs,
                        values = c("dashed", "twodash","dashed", "twodash"))
```

[image]